# Добавить много картинок в массив

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Такой вопрос:  есть много картинок которые нужно добавить в массив.
Картинки имеют название   от picture_1001.png и так до picture_1121.png. Каким образом это сделать, не добавлять же по одной?

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типо:
for (int i=Num;i>0;i--)
    {
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"6_%04i_1.png",i];
    }